# Displaying japanese characters from SQLException.getMessage()

Tags: java, mysql

I have a simple class which displays records having japanese characters from the database.
The character encoding for class file is UTF-8. I have also altered database to use charset UTF-8.

There is no problem displaying the records having japanese characters on console. No problem with hard coded too.

But when I try to enter the records with same userid (Primary key in table) as one of the old record. It throws SQLException that shows duplicate entry error message.But It shows junk characters. Like :

```
Duplicate entry 'ãƒ©ã‚±ã‚·ãƒ¥ï¼‘ï¼’ï¼“ï¼”ï¼•' for key 1
```

So what is the problem exactly. Why records are displayed correctly but not SQLException.getMessage();

Comment: Thank you for including the part about being able to display the characters from valid records and hard-coded messages on the console - that's saved some avenues of exploration.

Comment: Where is the error thrown to and displayed? System Console, IDE console, Log file, etc?

Comment: Error is thrown to Eclipse IDE console, and JSP page too. (Same result)

Comment: Hey, Is the error message copied from MySQL file (If they have stored error messages in the file, which may not be UTF-8)???? Because the error  message of Exception class and MySQL tool is same.

Comment: From where this error message is initialized to Exception object?

Comment: This may or may not be the culprit but `UTF-8` in MySQL is only 3-byte. `UTF-8` however, requires 1 to 4 bytes. If you want to grab 4-byte `UTF-8`, you need `utf8mb4` that accommodates/holds/occupies 4 bytes to be a true `UTF-8` character encoding standard. Only MySQL 5.5 or higher supports `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ラケシュ１２３４５
```

Correct?

Probably what happened when INSERTing was

- You had correct utf8 encoding for the data, and
- SET NAMES latin1 -- by default or by mistake, and
- The column (or table) the text was stored into was declared with `CHARACTER SET latin1`, again possibly by default.

You can verify that the data is stored correctly by doing

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) ...
```

If you fetch that string, the hex will be `E383A9E382B1E382B7E383A5EFBC91EFBC92EFBC93EFBC94EFBC95`.  Notice how there are groups of 6 hex, starting `E383` in the case of Katakana or `EFBC` for the "full width digits".

Assuming the table still says latin1, no data is lost, and the [2-step ALTER](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter) will fix it.  In summary:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (NOT NULL, etc) was already on the column.

(I could not give this clear and complete an answer to this question until very recently.)