# How is the error message initialized when an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, mysql

There is a String object called `detailMessage` in java.lang.Throwable class, which says the reason of any exception thrown in java code.

This object is initialized through a constructor using `super(string message)` statement or setter or whatever from subclasses like Exception and again from its subclasses like SQLException.

When SQLException is thrown, error message can be displayed using `sqlExceptionObject.getMessage();`

**The error message in sqlExceptionObject.getMessage() is same as in MySQL tool (Incase of any error in query execution)**

So is the error message copied from MySQL? If yes, then from where?

Comment: probably comes from a class in the mysql driver jar

Comment: Generally error code is returned from Database, then it's the job of the wrapper to show the user understandable message based on the code. So probably all this is done in the database driver.jar.

Comment: This problem may fix my previous problem : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503151/displaying-japanese-characters-from-sqlexception-getmessage)

Comment: Yes.@ScaryWombat, there are lots of classes in this library. Though I go through some of it.@Rakesh Juyal, there is a final class called MysqlErrorNumbers in com.mysql.jdbc, which contains all the codes regarding sql errors.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver is responsible for that. It could translate an error code it gets from the DB to a string or it could get the error string directly from the DB. I don't know which one is the case for MySQL.